# Angular2 New Form API: Submitting form without any bindings of its elements

Tags: forms, data-binding, angular

**Attention:  It should work with [the new forms API!](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)**

Is there a possibility to submit a raw form without any bindings of its elements?

An Example:

```
<div class="form-mantle">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm1(f1.value)" #f1="ngForm">
        <input ngControl="name1" name="name1" type="text" required/><br/>
        <input ngControl="text1" name="text1" type="text" required/><br/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!f1.form.valid">Next </button>
    </form>
</div>

<pre>
{{ form1 | json }}
</pre>
```

**How should onSubmitForm1() look like, so that I get form1 like below rendered:**

```
{
    name1: "Michael Jackson",
    text1: "They don't really care about us"
}
```

I've already preapared a component to copy+paste, for those, who want to help:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'form1',
    templateUrl: 'form1.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['form1.component.css']
})
export class Form1Component {

    form1 : any = {};

    constructor() { }

    onSubmitForm1 (data?:any) {
        // get raw data from form without bindings
        this.form1 = data;
        console.log("Data", data);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Edit: The exact working copy in plnkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/nMPTYLGxgWzzJuD9Be3f?p=preview) does not work within the seed from https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed . Maybe it is a version problem ??

[image: The delivered object is empty]

**Double binding works without errors:**

```
<div class="form-mantle">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm1(f1.value)" #f1="ngForm">
        <input [(ngModel)]="f1.name1" #name="ngModel" name="name1" type="text" required/><br/>
        <input [(ngModel)]="f1.text1" #name="ngModel" name="text1" type="text" required/><br/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!f1.form.valid">Next </button>
    </form>
</div>

<pre>
{{ f1.value | json }}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call it like so in your `ngSubmit`:

```html
(ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm1(f1.value)"
```

To every control you want to submit add the `ngControl` attribute to set its name:

```html
<input ngControl="name1" name="name1" type="text" required/><br/>
<input ngControl="text1" name="text1" type="text" required/><br/>
```

Then in your `onSubmitForm1`:

```js
onSubmitForm1 (data?:any) {
    console.log("Data", data);
    this.form1 = data;
}
```

---

> [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nMPTYLGxgWzzJuD9Be3f?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: I've tried it now and (f1.value) does unfortunately nothing :/

Comment: Check this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nMPTYLGxgWzzJuD9Be3f?p=preview

Comment: I've exacty the same copy, the object is empty, I edit my question above and add a screenshot. Maybe I've an version-problem, I use the seed from https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

Comment: I just saw, that the old forms are marked as deprecated in that seed in the `main.ts`. Just remove those two lines `disableDeprecatedForms()` and `provideForms()`. Then it should work fine.

Comment: But I want to use the newer version, that is the main question :)

Comment: I couldn't read that in your question ... I suggest a read then: https://medium.com/@jecelynyeen/building-form-with-latest-technique-in-angular-2-rc-2-f2f0fffc0f6f#.4ilpl7aqg

Comment: But that is with double data binding, what I want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, for now (rc4) you have only two ways for accepting a data after submit:

1) model-driven strategy (bindings)

2) template-driven strategy (ngControls)

Answer (score 0):

Finaly the following has worked (double bindings :/ ):

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()" #s1="ngForm">
    <input [(ngModel)]="step1.name1"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" required/><br/>
    <input [(ngModel)]="step1.text1"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" required/><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!s1.form.valid">Next </button>
</form>
```